# YoctoProject: change ownership of all files in a recipe

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

For the YoctoProject (v2.0, Jethro) the ownership of files inside the image defaults to user and group `root` unless I do explicitly change them by `chown` and `chgrp` in the `do_install` step for the given recipe.

I have a few recipes for which all files should be owned by another group and user than `root`. Is there a (cleaner/smarter) way to achieve this without calling `chown` and `chgrp` in `do_install`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BSP vendors do usually provide example recipes to solve basic tasks.
Usually folder is called "**recipes-skeleton**"

User/Group add recipe sample path for freescale BSP:
`~/yocto/fsl-community-bsp/sources/poky/meta-skeleton/recipes-skeleton/useradd/useradd-example.bb`

Same can be found on github:
https://github.com/dirtybit/gumstix-yocto/blob/master/meta-skeleton/recipes-skeleton/useradd/useradd-example.bb

For changing root user info look up `EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS` flag. Need to inherit "extrausers" class first. Documentation on class is at:
http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-classes-extrausers

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add user adding the following to your recipe.

```
inherit extrausers
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = " useradd user1; \
                       useradd user2; \
                       useradd user3; \
                       usermod  -p 'user1_psw' user1; \
                       usermod  -p 'user2_psw' user2; \
                       usermod  -p 'user3_psw' user3;\
                       usermod  -a -G sudo user1; \
                       usermod  -a -G sudo user2; \
                       usermod  -a -G sudo user3; "
```